# Merge tags "share-repurchase" and "buybacks"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Description for [share-repurchase](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/share-repurchase):

> Questions relating to companies buying back their own shares from the market.

Description for [buybacks](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buybacks):

> Stock buybacks refer to the repurchasing of shares of stock by the company that issued them.

Looks like they're the same thing. Should these tags be merged?

Comment: I'd suggest posting an answer saying they should be merged and identifying which one should "win". Then people can post an alternative if they disagree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree they are the same and should be merged. For what it's worth, I'd vote for "share-repurchase" since "buyback" is more colloquial (e.g. "buyback" in wikipedia links to "share repurchase").

Comment: I will implement this soon if there are no other views. Please ping me if I haven't done it by say the weekend (27th June) :-)

Comment: This is now done.